# To merge data of two tables according to condition -parent child relationship

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables workorder and wotasks.
  **SCRIPTS:** To create tables and  data  insertion script is as below

```
CREATE TABLE workorder  (
    wonum INT, siteid VARCHAR(5),reporteddate date
);

CREATE TABLE woTasks (
    wonum INT, siteid VARCHAR(5),parent INT
);


INSERT INTO workorder   (wonum,siteid,reporteddate) 
values 
(5000503,'MCT','01-DEC-2018'),
(5000504,'MCT','01-DEC-2018'),
(5000505,'MCT','11-DEC-2018'),
(5000506,'MCT','01-MAR-2018'),
(5000507,'MCT','21-FEB-2018'),
(5000508,'MCT','01-MAY-2018');

select * from workorder;

INSERT INTO woTasks (wonum,siteid,parent) 
values 
(5000531,'MCT','5000503'),
(5000532,'MCT','5000503'),
(50005061,'MCT','5000506'),
(50005062,'MCT','5000506'),
(50005063,'MCT','5000506'),
(50005081,'MCT','5000508');

select * from woTasks;
```

My requirement is to get data from these tables based on below conditions
 aLL WONUM  from workorder (where reported date >=1-May-2018 and  reported date <=31-DEC-2018)   +     all its child wonum from wotasks table
Result should be like this

```
wonum
50005003  
5000531 
5000532
5000505   
5000506    
50005061   
50005063 
5000508    
50005081  
5000504
```

kindly help me to write query for result as above

Comment: Your insert statements are syntactically wrong, please correct them. Another thing, `'01-DEC-2018'` is not a DATE it's a string. Always use `TO_DATE` to explicitly convert a string into date without depending on your locale specific NLS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issue with your data type for wonum and parent column. If I guess all columns are char type ouf value, you can use UNION ALL logic as below to achieve your desired output-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5cfcb3ad77a8fd9d9cccab55af1c94da)

```
SELECT wonum FROM workorder
UNION ALL
SELECT B.wonum FROM workorder A
INNER JOIN woTasks B ON A.wonum = B.parent
WHERE reporteddate >= '1-May-2018'
AND reporteddate <= '31-DEC-2018'
ORDER BY 1
```

But in case if all your values are Number, Just convert them to Char/String in the ORDER BY part to get your results ordered as you shown.